# Group by while maintaining access to other columns

Tags: sql-server

Table as example:

ID,Course Code, Begin Date, End Date, Instructor, Location, Year, Term

1,ACC 2112 1EB, 1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, Bob, Main, 2020, FA

2,ACC 2112 1EB, 1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, Bob, Main, 2020, SP

3,ACC 2112 1EB, 1/1/2019, 2/1/2019, Joe, Main, 2019, SP

4,ART 2201 1EB, 1/1/2020, 2/1/2020, Joe, Main, 2020, SP

I need to write a query that will convert courses in above table with ID of 1 & 2 to one course. This is done based on the combination of the course code and begin and end dates being the same. Other data in the row will be different.

I realize I could group these based on the course code, and start /end dates however I still need to know what the IDs of these courses are.

So essentially I am trying to create a mapping of these course codes. With the results looking like.

ID, MAPPED COURSE CODE

1, ACC 2112 1EB_2020

2, ACC 2112 1EB_2020

3, ACC 2112 1EB_2019_SP

4, ART 2201 1EB_2020_SP

Ideally this would be a view but I can use a stored procedure if necessary. Additionally rows 3 and 4 do not need to be present in the results but can be if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi from what i could understand this is what you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID int, CourseCode nvarchar(50), BeginDate Date, EndDate Date, 
             Instructor nvarchar(50), Location nvarchar(50), Year int , Term nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
       VALUES(1,'ACC 2112 1EB', '1/1/2020', '2/1/2020', 'Bob', 'Main', 2020, 'FA')
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
       VALUES(2,'ACC 2112 1EB', '1/1/2020', '2/1/2020', 'Bob', 'Main', 2020, 'SP')
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
       VALUES(3,'ACC 2112 1EB', '1/1/2019', '2/1/2019', 'Joe', 'Main', 2019, 'SP')
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
       VALUES(4,'ART 2201 1EB', '1/1/2020', '2/1/2020', 'Joe', 'Main', 2020, 'SP')

--The solution
SELECT ID, CourseCode 
FROM(
    SELECT ID, CourseCode + '_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4), Year) as CourseCode, 
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CourseCode, BeginDate, EndDate) as Converted
FROM @MyTable) as temp
WHERE Converted > 1
```

The COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CourseCode, BeginDate, EndDate) will count the courses you will merge together grouping by what is written in the PARTITION BY section. After that you simply select all the courses where COUNT was greater than 1 meaning that these courses were merged.